# Thinkpad Carbon X1 6th Generation Windows 10 - Screen Locks When Unplugging Power

Tags: windows-10, display, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

My 6th generation Carbon X1 goes into screen lock every time I unplug the power.  Is there anyway to prevent it from doing so on Windows 10?

Comment: I have an X1 (one earlier generation) - no issues. Update BIOS and Chipset (updates new in 2020), Power Driver, and then all other drivers.  Restart, update Windows 10 and test.

Comment: The time threshold for locking your screen on battery must be set too low. If you go into the advanced settings of your power plan, and try to set the timeout for turning your screen off to, say, 5 minutes, does it still happen? Do you have Lenovo PM (Power Management) installed on your PC? It's an inglorious piece of crop, that usually breaks about every bit of power management Windows tries to implement. The two go at each other's throat, with you caught in the middle... You can try one or several of the approaches depicted here too: https://www.guidingtech.com/turn-off-auto-lock-windows-10/

Comment: Never happened on my ThinkPad X1. Indeed the PM Driver is very necessary.